# Generate report from session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dataset, reporting, rdlc

i use RDLC to generate report from dataset normally, but this time i want to gerenrate just report for data before saving into database.
Can i generate RDLC report from data before updating it in data base? 
is there any way from the session (instead of the DataSet)  into RDLC report

Comment: in other words i have a wizard step, and i want to print all data that i have entred in all the previous step before confirmation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DataSet`/`DataTable` created and populated at runtime with data collected from your wizard and use it as a `ReportDataSource` for your report.

Please note that if your wizard collects a *very small number of data* you can pass them as `ReportParameter`, but I don't recommend this solution.

Comment: I have used dataset but in other cases, here it doesn't work just because i want to print data that it didn't stored yet in data base !

Comment: DataSet and DataTable can be disconnected from database. You can create and fill these object at runtime with every type of data you need.

Comment: i'm trying like this exemple with dataset
[ http://dotnetawesome.com/mvc/microsoft-report-in-mvc-4 ]
but, in my case what shall i do ?
shal i make an instance of view model ?

Comment: DataTable catdt = Session["categories"] as DataTable;
i'm using this bind but the value is always Null